# Ruby on Rails on GoDaddy VPS Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-hosting

So, I have a client who wants his site hosted on GoDaddy, and it's a RoR site I built for him. It's on a VPS server, so I can connect via SSH and do everything I need to do, but I'm not sure what I should do to actually serve the site. On Digital Ocean I would have installed and configured Puma and Nginx, but I'm not sure if I should configure something through CPanel instead.

If so, I'm not sure how to do that. Anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

I talked my client into using Digital Ocean. GoDaddy is a nightmare for Rails.